# Value in cell as variable in select formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have programmed the following VBA code:

```
Sub test()
Dim Variable As Variant
Variable = "R2:R11"
Sheet1.Select
Range(Variable).Select
End Sub
```

This formula works perfectly. Now I want to replace the "R2:R11" part of the variable and instead referring to a cell (W12) in the spreadsheet. In this cell I have written "R2:R11" and I changed the formula to the following:

```
Variable = Sheet1.Range("W12")
```

which leads to the following code:

```
Sub test()
Dim Variable As Variant
Variable = Sheet1.Range("W12")
Sheet1.Select
Range(Variable).Select
End Sub
```

However, with this formula I now get the ERROR 1004.

Do you guys have any solution how I can make the variable referring to the cell in the spreadsheet and then use it in the select formula?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Works fine for me although I'm not sure I would use that methodology.

Comment: have you tried `Variable = Sheet1.Range("W12").Value`

Comment: It will work correctly if your w12 cell contains Range like "R2:R11"  (without quotes) . If w12 contains string like Hello or numeric like 23 you will get error 1004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your variables properly and access the actual `.Value` property of the Range object.

```
Sub test()
Dim Variable As String
Variable = Sheet1.Range("W12").Value
Sheet1.Select
Range(Variable).Select
End Sub
```

Which can also be written as:

```
Sub test()
Sheet1.Activate
Range([W12]).Activate
End Sub
```

---

A note on the `.Value` property - if you omit this, the value will usually be assigned anyway because it's the default property of the range object. That being said there are scenarios where this won't be the case and therefore it's always best practice to explicitly state that you want the value.

Comment: Even with your nice code if OP does not ensure appropriate data in cell W12 like R2:R11 , he is likely to get error 1004.

Comment: as per my "tests" (quite a few indeed..) I think the OP's issue _has_ to be the double quotes actually typed in the cell content. If you type them, error 1004 is thrown by either codes (with `Variant` or `String` type variables)

Comment: @skakkar: seems we're "in phase" today!

Comment: so the issue was not the double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

you most probably typed `"R2:R11"` in W12 cell, i.e with double quotes too
in that cell you only have to type  `R1:R12`

moreover you can simply code

```
Sub test()
   Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Range("W12")).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: well, should those double quotes be the issue then @skkakkar resolved it while I was typing -> credits to him!